# preform jquery function on browser shrink

Tags: jquery

Hello I have this function that preforms jquery on specific widths, I like it and it works fine but the only drawback is that the browser has to be refreshed for the function to kick in. Check my code below

```
function checkWidth() {
    if (jQuery(window).width() < 1199) {
        //do something
    } else {

    }
};
checkWidth();
```

So what this function says is that when the screen is below 1199 px, then preform the function but when you start out above 1199px then move the browser below 1199px, the page needs to be reloaded.

The point of this is to target tablet. I know that tablet cant go bigger than that so any time a user opens the page up on tablet this is not an issue, but I am a little picky and would like this to work when a user opens it up in a browser and then shrinks the browser.

Is it possible to modify this function so it will work on browser shrink instead of having to refresh?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`resize`](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) event on `window`. The following will call your `checkWidth()` function every time a browser resize occurs:

```
$(window).on('resize', checkWidth);
```

But of course you can achieve this using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) instead.

Comment: @cup_of That is the example?

Comment: of sorry i thought there was more, so just place this before my code?

Comment: Yes, but be sure to wrap it inside a DOMReady function.

Comment: awesome thank you. ill accept your answer when it allows me too

Answer (score 1):

The method you are looking for is .resize(). Here is the jquery documentation that you can refer to: https://api.jquery.com/resize/ and also here you can see an example: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_resize.asp.

You should call the function inside

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    checkWidth();
});

checkWidth();
```

and also outside of .resize() method, just like on example above. This will call your function when the page loads and also when the user will resize the browser window. Of course it all goes inside

```
$( document ).ready().
```